# In str_replace() and str_ireplace() if both FIND and REPLACE are arrays and FIND has fewer elements than REPLACE then what will be the output?

Tags: php, arrays, string, function

In PHP there are two string functions str_replace() and str_ireplace().

They have syntax

```
str_replace (find, replace, string, count)
```

and

```
str_ireplace (find, replace, string, count)
```

If both `find` and `replace` are arrays and `find` has fewer elements than `replace` then what will be the output?

Comment: Try and see. I suspect the extra items in `replace` will be ignored.

Comment: `str_ireplace — Case-insensitive version of str_replace()` so it will be the same output if the both parameters have the same characters case

Comment: Hassan please read my question properly first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will hold true for both `str_replace()` and `str_ireplace()`:

The `$replace` elements that do not have a corresponding `$search` element will be silently ignored.

```
$search  = array('This');
$replace = array('new1','new2');
$subject = 'This and that';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
//output: new1 and that
```

---

The `$search` elements that do not have a corresponding `$replace` element will be replaced by an empty string (effectively removed).

```
$search  = array('This','that');
$replace = array('new1');
$subject = 'This and that';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
//output: new1 and
```

---

While I'm at it, here is another important behavior to observe: `str_replace()` is key-ignorant.

```
$search  = array(1=>'This',0=>'that');
$replace = array(0=>'new1',1=>'new2');
$subject = 'This and that';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
//output: new1 and new2
//if keys were recognized, it would be: new2 and new1
```

Comment: Is there any method to make the str_replace() function to recognize key? Also does this fact that keys are not recognized holds true for str_ireplace() function as well?

Comment: @cyano_learner I'd say pre-sort and key check (and possibly element "pad") both arrays before feeding them into str_replace().